# If I reset after each run, how many times do I need to repeat an experiment to have a 75% chance of running it on all the subjects?

Tags: probability

Suppose there is a bag with 100 marbles. And I can draw 5 marbles in one attempt. But after that draw I have to put the marbles back. In how many attempts do I have a 75% chance that I have drawn each marble at least once?

I wrote a brute force program that calculated this:

```
Marbles = 100. DRAW 5 at a time. Performing 100000 runs.
Runs completed = 10000
Runs completed = 20000
Runs completed = 30000
Runs completed = 40000
Runs completed = 50000
Runs completed = 60000
Runs completed = 70000
Runs completed = 80000
Runs completed = 90000
Runs completed = 100000
For 75% confidence you need 115 draws.
```

But how can we mathematically arrive at the same answer?

Comment: I think that the answer would consist of a binomial process. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: Eg $n=100$, $k=5$ ?

Comment: This is similar to the [Coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), but the analysis is more difficult if you pick 5 marbles each time.

Comment: This is known as the "Batched Coupon Collector's problem". There are some results online for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if the following argument does not have a flaw (dependence/independence worries mainly at the last step) but here is the idea:

1. When you perform a single draw of 5 marbles the probability that a fixed marble A **shows up** is:  $ p = {99 \choose 4} / {100 \choose 5} = 5/100$. Why? Well, we have $100 \choose 5$ 5-element subsets in total. Marble A is a member of $99 \choose 4$ of these subsets. Hence this probability value.
2. So when you perform a single draw of 5 marbles the probability that marble A **does not show up** is:  $ 1-p = 95 / 100$
3. Different draws are independent obviously. So the after N draws the probability that marble A **does not show up** is: $(1-p)^N$
4. $\Rightarrow$ After N draws the probability that marble A **shows up** is: $1 - (1-p)^N$
5. *This last step I am not quite sure about... because I am not sure if I can multiply these probabilities (not sure if these events here are independent, my intuition tells me they are but somehow I am not fully convinced)...* Anyway, the argument here goes like this. So now since we have 100 marbles (not just marble A) the probability that after N draws **all of them show up** is simply the product: $p_N = (1 - (1-p)^N)^{100}$

I put this formula into a computer program and I see that:
$p_N \ge 0.75$ when $N \ge 115$.

How do we find the value $115$ mathematically? Well, by solving this inequality

$(1 - (1-p)^N)^{100} \ge 0.75$  for $N$.

We solve it and we get:

$N \ge log_{\frac{95}{100}}(1 - 0.75^{0.01}) \approx 114.1 $

Since N is an integer, we get $N \ge 115 $

I was able to empirically confirm this numeric result.
So now I am slightly more convinced that my argument in the last step is OK.

Comment: I would be glad if someone confirms or rejects this.

Comment: When you draw M marbles from a bag of N, the probability that you get a specific marble is simply M/N - unclear where you got that probability in step 1.

Comment: @NuclearWang Thanks, you helped me to find a small mistake here. It is $99 \choose 4$, not $100 \choose 4$

Comment: The events in the last step are not independent though: the fact that a marble shows up reduces the probability that other ones did.

Comment: @Raoul But why? In each single draw, when we draw the 5 marbles don't we draw them at once/simultaneously? See also this question which I asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3614613/lottery-scenario-independent-events-or-not

Comment: (coming from the other question) Your steps are not "actually correct". However, because you require an integer number of trials $N \geq 114.1$, that rounding effect could be sufficient to "make the numerical answer correct". There could be cases, say you calculate that $N \geq 114.99$, then $N=115$ isn't the actual answer, but $N=116$ instead.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yeah, I realized all that, thanks. Even here - I am not sure what my exact error value is... If the actual answer is 113.8 and not 114.1, then the integer answer would be 114 and not 115. So how do I know :) ? Thanks anyways, it was a nice try from my side. I just had that intuition that in 5. something is not quite right, but also that these events are "almost independent".

Comment: Thanks @peter.petrov! I tested your formula with the results of my brute force simulation program and the results always match with a small margin of error. So your logic appears to be very sound to me! 

Brute force results - 
Marbles 1000, draw 40, N=200
Marbles 2000, draw 70 , N=249
Marbles 3000, draw 20, N=1383 (your formula gives 1384)
Marbles 4000, draw 137, N=276 (your formula gives 274)

Note: I only used 10,000 runs in the above simulations, so the results are likely to be slightly inaccurate.